# How do I pick elements from a block using a string in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

Given this block

```
fs: [
 usr [
  local [
   bin []
  ]
  share []
 ]
 bin []
]
```

I could retrieve an item using a path notation like so:

```
fs/usr/local
```

How do I do the same when the path is a string?

```
path: "/usr/local"
find fs path ;does not work!
find fs to-path path ;does not work!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to complete the input string path with the right root, then LOAD it and evaluate it.

```
>> path: "/usr/local"
>> insert path "fs"
>> do load path
== [
    bin []
]
```

Comment: Ah, nice! Thank you! I trimmed it to this -- 

do join 'fs path

Comment: @DocKimbel, is this what you actually get as output in either R2 or R3? I'm not getting the same...

Comment: @Adrian, tested with 2.7.6.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know Rebol has a **native path type**?

although this doesn't exactly answer your question, I tought I'd add a reference on how to use paths directly in Rebol.  Rebol has ***a lot*** of datatypes, and when you can, you should leverage that rich language feature.  Especially when you start to use and build dialects, knowing what types exist and how to use them becomes even more potent.

Here is an example on how you can build and run a path directly, without using strings.  in order to represent a path within source code, you use the **lit-path!** datatype.

example:

```
>> p: 'fs/usr/local
== fs/usr/local
>> do p
== [
    bin []
]
```

you can even append to a path to manipulate it:

```
>> append p 'bin
== fs/usr/local/bin
>> do p
== []
```

if it where stored within a block, you use a path! type directly (not a lit-path!):

```
>> p: [fs/usr/local/bin]
== [fs/usr/local]
>> do first p
== [
    bin []
]
```

also note that using paths directly has advantages over using strings because the path is composed of a series of words, which you can do some manipulation more easily than with strings example:

```
>> head change next p 'bin
== fs/bin/local

>> p: 'fs/path/issue/is
== fs/path/issue/is
>> head replace p 'is  'was
== fs/path/issue/w
```

as opposed to using a string:

```
>> p: "fs/path/issue/is"
== "fs/path/issue/is"
>> head replace p "is"  "was"
== "fs/path/wassue/is"
```

If you want to browse the disk, instead of Rebol datasets, you must simply give 'FS a value of a file! and the rest of the path with browse from there (this is how paths work on file! types):

```
fs: %/c/ 
read dirize fs/windows
```

Comment: have you tested the examples in R2 or R3? I get an error when I try the first example (but with a Windows path).

Comment: @Adrian, DockKimble's solution above, worked for me, what error do you see? Also, what do you mean by Windows path? Rebol's path type requires forward slashes afaik.

Comment: @Moliad, yes I'm aware of the path type. But thank you for explaining it here.

Comment: @rebnoob: When you try to do `p: '/c/utils`, for example, you get ** Syntax error: invalid "word-lit" -- "'". So you can't use a literal to refer to an absolute path.

Comment: @Adrian path! is not (essentially) for disk paths, but for rebol code browsing, so what you tried in essence makes no sense.  if you want to browse the disk, instead of rebol datasets, you must simply give 'FS a value of file! and the rest of the path with browse from there... `fs: %/c/  read dirize fs/windows`  this works in both R2 & R3. I've edited the post to include this example.